# Chosen.js search not working on dynamically Ajax replaced comboboxes

Tags: jquery-chosen

I'm dynamically replacing some select tags via Ajax calls (jQuery load() method).
On the new select, I call .chosen(). Chosen is applied but search not work.

Tried to issue a .trigger("chosen:updated"); and does not work.
The chosen search still not work on the new select.

The search work perfectly on statically added select (hardcoded in my html source).